# woocommerce storefront sidebar out of place

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, themes, storefront

I have added some widgets to sidebar to enable it and it appears fine on all the pages except the single product page. Instead on the right side of the content it is out of the product area on the bottom right.

Here is the link to the page: http://bends.syntaxbase.co.uk/product/42mm-1d-stainless-steel-bend/

Image of how the sidebar appears:

[image]

I can't see any function or hooks that have been used to change the sidebar position and can't see anything in the settings.

Comment: This is issue of close <div> tag. If you provide the code then I give you proper solution.

Comment: Which code do you need, html or the theme code. Also I haven't changes the theme code directly only through hooks so I not sure how a div could have been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dhruvin Moradiya

I start analysing the site carefully and disable all the extra plugins and the side started working. I found out it was one of the plugins I was developing that had an extra closing DIV. I've found the problem and fixed it.

I'm new to Stack Overflow and couldn't find a way of crediting  'Dhruvin Moradiya' for pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: I can't see any option to vote next to your comment.